# How to clean up Mac Python?

Tags: python, unix

I installed multiple version of Python in my Mac and it's very chaotic. Right now, when I want to use Python via VSCode, only Python 3.9.7 works.

How can I delete all pythons expcet for the system one?

[Multiple Pythons on my mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQXXy.png)

I already tried to identify each python I installed,

`which python`
`/usr/local/bin/python`

`which python3`
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`

How can I delete all the other pythons?

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/1987/

Comment: Unless you are pressed for disk space *and* these multiple versions are a significant cause of that, I would just ignore them. Pick *one* method for managing Python version, use that to clean up any old versions *it* installed that you don't need anymore, and be discipline about *only* using that tool in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Python Installed in the machine or not from terminal?
   python3 --version
2. Check the pip installation from terminal
   pip3 --version
3. Check the location of the installed Python
   which python3
4. Go to Installed location of the Python (command + shift + G)
5. Remove python folder in that location
6. Remove python application from mac “Applications”
7. Check the python installation again from terminal
   python3 --version
8. Check the pip installation again from terminal
   pip3 --version
   with this you can get rid of whole python from your machine
   then again you can install the latest version