# Can't find /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm using an M1 MacBook. When trying to learn Python a year ago I naively installed too many versions of python in too many ways (homebrew, anaconda, official website), so I had a similar problem as he has:

[How to clean up Mac Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783218/how-to-clean-up-mac-python/75783485#75783485)

Now, after uninstalling homebrew, anaconda and cleaning up dependencies (as far as I could), I don't have a `Python.framework` file anymore.

I tried to understand VikingOSXs answer on this:

[Creating a python framework in system/library/frameworks](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253882372)

but I already lost it after the first sentence.
Running the command `ls -a /usr/local/bin/python*` gets me this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3          /usr/local/bin/python3.10-intel64
/usr/local/bin/python3-config       /usr/local/bin/python3.11
/usr/local/bin/python3-intel64      /usr/local/bin/python3.11-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.10       /usr/local/bin/python3.11-intel64
/usr/local/bin/python3.10-config
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, after uninstalling homebrew, anaconda and cleaning up
> dependencies (as far as I could), I don't have a Python.framework file
> anymore.

So you've removed too much python. I would just reinstall python from https://www.python.org/downloads/

FWIW, I have those same files, and also have installed from python.org. Brew puts stuff elsewhere; I don't know about anaconda. My python Framework is in `/Library`, not `/System/Library/`.

Apple doesn't include python frameworks in the OS by default.